# after run pip install firebase-admin getting error

Tags: python, firebase, pip, firebase-admin, pyopenssl

I have install firebase-admin in python2, but it module is not installing and getting following error.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AttributeError%3A+%27module%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST%27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have fixed this by removing the python-openssl package (and it's dependencies) with:

> apt-get --auto-remove remove python-openssl

Then installing the latest version with pip:

> pip install pyOpenSSL